# Problem with sending POST Request and Recieving it, Special chars are not showing

Tags: php, post, python-requests, get

Hi stackoverflow users!

I encountered a problem when i was coding my login api.
I want to send a POST request with special characters. ! and @ worked fine but when i tried adding # it brokes.

[Here is an example of what im saying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXXo4.png)

I've tried googling but no result, I even entered google second page (kinda depression)
I tried adding many php tags to fix it, tried changing settings of php but I'm probably searching wrong...

This is how I'm doing it, pretty basic.

```
    $login = $_GET["login"];
    $password = $_GET["password"];
```

I would love if someone would tell me a fix I'm struggling for hours to fix it...

Comment: You're not really sending your login request with the password visible in the GET parameters are you? If so, please don't. That URL can and will be cached in the browser - not to mention visible to all networks it travels through - in other words, a major security risk. Use POST and SSL.

Comment: That's not a POST request. Use `method="POST"` in your HTML form and then `$_POST` in your PHP.

Comment: But for future reference [`urlencode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) for stuff that makes sense on a querystring The `#` has a special meaning on a querystring

Comment: @Kinglish is correct, it's a bad idea to send password like that. But in general, if you have special characters in the URL, use [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

Answer (score 0):

you should not use GET to pass any type of login or password, is very vulnerable and is subject to this type of occurrence with the special characters.
Use instead of GET the POST method, below is the example of use through POSTMAN.
And a part of the PHP code for receiving the POST method and the correct return of the information.

[image]

PHP code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: token, login, password, sync");
echo json_encode((object)[
    "success" => true,
    "body" => $_POST['password'],
]);
```

If you want to test your code, you can use https://upwork.codefusiontm.com/auth/password
Pass the **password** parameter with the **POST** method, the REST API will return a JSON with success and the body.